# specify path of cropped image in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

Is there a way to specify where an image should be saved after cropping? Say I open the gallery, get an image, and then launch an intent to crop the image. Is there a way to pass the destination of the cropped image to the intent?

Comment: *launch an intent to crop the image* [THERE IS NO SUCH INTENT!](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html)

Comment: @Selvin Yes there is: `Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");` Otherwise how do you crop an image in android?

Comment: FSM save us! no, there is no, please read the blog entry, also please show me it in android's sdk documentation ...